# How to ALWAYS link an image in MS Word 2010 instead of embedding it?

Tags: microsoft-word, images, microsoft-word-2010, hyperlink

I want to only link, not embed, pictures in my Word document. Yet I got a lot of images to insert!

And I want to spare me the additional click into the dropdown menu one and for all, so the question is, is there any way to set "link image(s)" **as default**? Because I didn't find anything in the Word **settings**, only totally useless detail settings. This "detail" has been overseen by Microsoft it seems! :(

I would provide you with a screenshot, but it would be German anyways. 
I think the guys who use image linking in Word since v2007, will know what I mean.

Thank you in advance!

Best regards

Comment: No one got any idea? :/

Comment: I came across your question as I was searching for a way to BREAK the links to images and save them within the document, which is described on the page linked below. It seems my Word 2010 default IS to link images. Did you ever get an answer to your question about how to always link images? [http://www.onemanwrites.co.uk/2011/09/13/how-to-embed-linked-images-in-word-2010/](http://www.onemanwrites.co.uk/2011/09/13/how-to-embed-linked-images-in-word-2010/)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of any options in Word to do this, but I wrote you a simple macro instead, which will link the image you choose from the window that pops up.

```
Sub AlwaysLinkImage()
' Macro by Fluxenein
Dim strFile As String
With Application.FileDialog(1) ' msoFileDialogOpen
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Image files", "*.bmp;*.gif;*.jpg;*.png"
    If .Show Then
        strFile = .SelectedItems(1)
        Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=strFile, _
            LinkToFile:=True, SaveWithDocument:=False
    Else
        MsgBox "You have not selected a file to link", vbExclamation
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Add the macro.You can now assign a button for the macro in the Quick access ribbon so you can click on this instead of the Insert-->Picture then choose from the dropdown and all..

1. Click on record macro

[image]

2.Give it a name and click button, then ok
[image]

3.Word options will popup, now simply add the macro, and it should be a button in quick access.
[image]

4.Click on the newly added button and go to view-->Macro-->View Macros and run your macro.
[image]

1. Choose an image, and the macro will link the image you choose. This is only to set up the button as an alternative to the actual picture insert button. After this, go to view-->Macro-->Stop recording. The button will now work, linking images you choose, saving you time from choosing "link images" in the dropdown in the insert image window.

If you want to Insert and Link, change the "SaveWithDocument:=False" in the macro to "SaveWithDocument:=True". You will have to remove button and edit macro, redo all steps again if so.

Comment: Well documented. Good job.